# How to create a rollover for an image box?

Tags: javascript, image, html, widget, rollover-effect

I have a container (500px width and height 800px).  THe container users an image as a background and in the middle I want to add a button that says "sign up."  When a user clicks on the sign up button I want a sign up form that pops in the same container.

In other words I need a rollover effect where the background changes color to something else and the same container is used a sign up box.  And I need the transformation to stay until the user hits the close button or something like that.

How can I accomplish this? Any ideas will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can place the 2 containers on top of each other and fade in/out the top one - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/k6kKR/)

***HTML***

```
<section>
    <div id="lower">
        <button> Close </button>
    </div>

    <div id="upper">
        <button> Sign up </button>
    </div>
</section>
```

***CSS***

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}

#lower { background: honeydew; }
#upper { background: beige; }
```

***jQuery***

```
$("#upper button").on("click", function() {
    $("#upper").fadeOut(300);
});


$("#lower button").on("click", function() {
    $("#upper").fadeIn(300);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Zoltan! Looks like I can make this work by adding the form in the second container.

Comment: exactly - place anything you want in the containers and you're good to go :)

Comment: Thanks man! I will followup here if something doesn't work.  Thanks ZOltan!

Comment: Hey, i started to use the script now but when i click on your test script on my server it won't work.  And I am using: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script> 

Any idea why it won't work?

Comment: have no idea what's wrong on your side.. first guess - you're calling the script before the DOM is ready

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I am actually new to using javascript so not sure what you mean? possible for you to explain a bit more in detail? Thanks again.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/  it's a good habit to put all your code in a `$(function() { ... }`